# Get an array of rows from a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, row, multiple-columns

I have this code...

```
$results_query = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE string LIKE '%" . $search_deliminator . "%'";
$results_result = $database->query($results_query);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($results_result);
```

What I'm trying to do is pull all the rows in which the *string* column contains my search deliminator. Further, I would like to get the values from each column of the rows.

How would I pull the multidimensional array I need containing each row, and each value of each column within each row?

**EDIT:**

I'm looking to do something to this effect...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results_result)) {

    $result[] = $row;

}
```

Then echo each column like this...

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row["0"];
}
```

Comment: What database class are you using?

Comment: Are you using mysql_, mysqli, or PDO? I havent seen the mysql_ driver used as an object before.

Comment: The class just handles the connection. I totally forgot about explaining that. I've just never used anything other than simple one-column queries. I think what I'm having a hard time understanding is what to use in the _$result_ variable.

Comment: you need to do your `$result = mysql_fetch_array($results_result);` in a loop - ie. `while($result = mysql_fetch_array($results_result)){ //print_r($result); }`

Comment: @Sean, I could do it in a variable declaration loop, right? I.E. assign each row to an array during the loop, then I would have my MD array?

Comment: This is basic foreach looping:

`foreach($result as $key => $value){
    //do some stuff with $value which now contains your row in an array where each
    //column is an index
}
`

Comment: The column name is the key in the foreach loop.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a flattened array of the result set, try this:

```
$result = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results_result)) {
    $result[$row['id']] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Also, you should look into either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) to replace the (now deprecated) MySQL extension.

Comment: I'm unsure what a flattened array is. Could I use something like, _while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results_result)) {
  
    $result[] = $row;
 
 }_ and then use a for each loop? I.E., _foreach ($result as $a_row) {
   echo $a_row["0"];
}_

Comment: See question edit for a better description of what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you're just looking to output the data, that's best done directly in the while loop. However, if you want to store the MySQL results in a variable so that it can be used elsewhere, using a while loop to build that variable would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you use PDO, you can use the `fetchAll()` method:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

With mysql or mysqli, you use a loop:

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results_result)) {

 $result[$i]["column1"] = $row["column1"];
 $result[$i]["column2"] = $row["column2"];
 $i++;
}
```

To display the output use:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
 echo $row["column1"];
 echo $row["column2"];
}
```